# What is the distortion model for coefficients estimated using "cv::aruco::calibrateCameraCharuco"?

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration, distortion, aruco

I am trying to calibrate my smartphone (with AE/AF locked) using a ChArUco board. For that, I am using "cv::aruco::calibrateCameraCharuco" and have implemented a pipeline referring to the link [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/da/d13/tutorial_aruco_calibration.html) (**Inputs to the pipeline**: photos of the ChArUco board captured using the smartphone and **Outputs**: camera matrix, 3x3 and distortion coefficients (k1,k2,p1,p2[,k3[,k4,k5,k6],[s1,s2,s3,s4]]) of 4, 5, 8 or 12 elements). I have a fairly good idea about the elements in the camera matrix, but I am confused about the distortion coefficients. Can someone please point me to a resource where I can read about the distortion model that is being used by "cv::aruco::calibrateCameraCharuco"?. Specifically, I am trying to understand that if I estimate all the 12 elements above, what does that mean mathematically? I did find some details [here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/calib3d/camera_calibration/camera_calibration.html), but this link contains information only on a very simple distortion model. Thanks in advance.

Edit: I found a related link [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga3207604e4b1a1758aa66acb6ed5aa65d)  that explains the camera distortion model. Basically, k1, k2, k3, k4, k5, and k6 are radial distortion coefficients; p1 and p2 are tangential distortion coefficients; and s1, s2, s3, and s4, are the thin prism distortion coefficients.